# Get all Regional CultureInfos form a Standard CultureInfo

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I'm quite new in C#. What I want is the following:

I have two comboboxes:

- In the first one I have all the standard languages (en, de, fr, ...)
- And in the second one I want to get the regional languages form the selected language in the first combobox (if I would select "en" then there should be listed "en-US", "en-GB", ...)

Can anyone help me with that? :D

Greez
Arion

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
var parent = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
var regionalLanguages = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                                   .Where(x => x.Parent.Equals(parent));
```

Comment: Hm... The regionalLanguages is Count = 0 if my selectedLanguage is "en". I think thats not correct.^^

Comment: Please try again with the current code. The first version i posted was not correct as it wasn't using `Equals` but `==`. Also, please note that `selectedLanguage` should be a string containing the language, e.g. "en". Other than that, I don't what more could be the problem as I have tested the code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way but this works:

1. Create a `Dictionary<CultureInfo, HashSet<CultureInfo>>` that maps the neutral cultures to country specific cultures.
2. Call [CultureInfo.GetCultures()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures) to get all the installed cultures.
3. For each CultureInfo returned call [IsNeutral](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.isneutralculture.aspx) to see if it is a neutral culture. If so, add it to the dictionary with an empty hashset as the value. If not, call [CultureInfo.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent) until you get to a neutral culture then add both the neutral culture as the key and the country specific culture to the HashSet.

Note that some country neutral cultures appear to be country specific, such as zh-Hans (Chinese Simplified) and zh-Hant (Chinese Traditional). You will also get some legacy cultures, like zh-CHS and zh-CHT (one again Chinese Simplified and Traditional) also may get some with diacritics.

Comment: It definitely can be easier. But it works as well. :D
Thank your for your help.